# Not Null constrain failed Integrity Error

Tags: python, django, null

Hi I am having trouble figuring out how to solve this error. I was creating a form to be able to add new topics to a website I am working on. After creating the form and trying to use it to submit a request to add a new topic I got a integrityError which I haven't encountered before. After doing some research I know it has something to do with a foreign key relationship where there is a field that is empty inside the database but I am not sure how to root cause it.

[image: error that Django is reporting]

here is my Models.py file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    """A category the user is writing about"""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string represtation of the model."""
        return self.text


class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic that is associated with a certain Category"""
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Topics'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string represtation of the model."""
        return self.text


class Entry(models.Model):
    """A entry associated with a certain topic"""
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return string represtation of the model."""
        return self.text[:50] + "..."
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Category, Topic


class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}


class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ['text']
        labels = {'text': ''}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse


from .models import Category, Entry, Topic
from .forms import CategoryForm, TopicForm
# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    """The home page for Learning Logs"""
    return render(request, 'blogging_logs/index.html')


def categories(request):
    """show all categories"""
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'blogging_logs/categories.html', context)


def topics(request, category_id):
    """Show all topics for a single category"""
    category = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)  # get category that was requested
    topics = category.topic_set.all()  # get all topics associated with category that was requested
    context = {'category': category, 'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'blogging_logs/category.html', context)


def topic(request, entry_id):
    """Show entry for single topic"""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=entry_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.all()
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'blogging_logs/topic.html', context)


def new_category(request):
    """Add a new category"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank formself.
        form = CategoryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted; process data
        form = CategoryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogging_logs:categories'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogging_logs/new_category.html', context)


def new_topic(request):
    """ Add new topic to category """
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # No data submitted; create a blank formself.
        form = TopicForm()
    else:
        form = TopicForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('blogging_logs:topics'))

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogging_logs/new_topic.html', context)
```

Any help to point me in the right direction is appreciated thank you!

**Select Category**

[image]

**Add new topic to category**

[image]

Comment: You need to add the `category` field to your `TopicForm` `fields`

Comment: Prior to getting to the page where you can click to add a topic you must select a category. My intention was to submit a new topic to the category that was selected. I am thinking that my error is it doesn't know what category was selected. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Yes, there doesn't seem to be a place where you pass that info to `Topic` creation page. You may need to use a hidden `Category` field and use `initial=` while initializing your form. Can you post your templates?

Answer (score 0):

```
    class Topic(models.Model):
       category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
       #your other fields
```

Run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` command, the error will be removed.